# If the husband is the only one earning money, does only the husband have the right to spend money or do both of them

Tags: nikah

Is the husband the only one who had the right to spend the money, or does the wife also have the right.

Answer (score 3):

Even if the husband is the one he works and earn money, he have to give his wife and his family money to spend and buy what they need. (it's not an option)

So the man is responsible of taking care and supporting his family with all their needs.
and if he didn't give them the proper life and stopped supporting his family. his wife had the right to complain to the judge or the authorities.

Answer (score 0):

If the husband is the only one who is earning the money then either he can spend money completely or he can give some money to his wife so that both can spend.

Also if wife is supporting/encouraging husband in spending money then its reward will also be given to her in sha allah.

Because at one place in QURAN it is said "Help each other in doing good deed",
So if wife support her husband in spending money then she will also get reward on it.